# views_get_view in combination with i18nviews only translates part of header

Tags: 7, views, i18n-l10n

I'm using the following code to get a view and render it

```
  $view = views_get_view('viewname');
  $view->set_display('page');

  $view->set_arguments(array($type));

  $view->pre_execute();
  $view->execute();

  return $view->render();
```

Works great but some fields of the exposed filters and the header are not getting translated. I'm using the i18nviews modules.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using the following code triggers i18nviews correctly:

```
$view = views_get_view('viewname');
$view->set_display('page', array($type));
```